# what is the difference between protobuf serialize in python and java?

Tags: python, java, protobuf-net, protobuf-java

I try to use java and python protobuf serialize method,such as

in python, the api is

```
SerializeToString
```

in java ,the api is

```
toByteArray
```

the result is the same? if not , how can i translate the java result as python result?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the different naming is because of conventions in these respective languages:

- In Python 2, a string (`str`) was a series of bytes, hence `SerializeToString`. In Python 3 we have the `bytes` type for byte strings, but the name was kept.
- In Java, the returned value is a `byte[]` so the name `toByteArray` makes sense.

However, despite the differences in API, the protobuf serialization format "on the wire" (or on disk) is [fully compatible](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview#cross-lang) between languages and platforms:

> The same messages can be read by code written in any supported programming language. You can have a Java program on one platform capture data from one software system, serialize it based on a `.proto` definition, and then extract specific values from that serialized data in a separate Python application running on another platform.

Comment: I use python3 to serialize the proto, and save it on disk. Then i use java to parse it directly from disk, it is worked. but after i parse it by java, i try to use "new String(myproto.toByteArray())" to serialize on disk by another file, i cannot parse it again

Comment: Please open a new question for that, and show the complete file writing code there.